# Why is this code wrong? There's a syntax error at time

Tags: python

```
time=int(input("How long do you spend on the computer per day?"))  
IF time =<2
print("that seems reasonable")
```

There is a syntax error at `time` on the second line and I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Have you at least spent a minute on google searching for "python if tutorial" or "python greater lower comparison"? 
StackOverflow is not here for helping on such basic things.

Comment: @Apero This question fits perfectly into StackOverflow. It concerns specific problem, it is concise. StackOverflow is also for begginers. I don't really understand downvotes here.

Comment: I disagree, we all started as beginners. But reading the documentation and learning through it or tutorials is the first thing to do. Then, StackOverflow is here to help getting even better.

Comment: It's hard to Google something like this, and I don't think the Python tutorial mentions that the language is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

- There's no `IF` in python, you mean `if`
- also, you mean `>=` instead of `=>`
- further, you need a `:` at the end of an `if` statement

So here you go:

```
time= int(input('How long do you spend on the computer? '))
if time >= 2:
    print('That seems reasonable')
```

Comment: @Matt: don't forget to mark an accepted answer so as to let everyone know the question has been resolved